# Can redis_exporter docker container not run on Redis server?

Tags: docker, redis

Redis servers: `192.168.0.5, 192.168.0.6, 192.168.0.7`

`redis_exporter` is installed in a docker container. The docker container can run a machine that is not a Redis server, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, per my experience. It can run on or not on 192.168.0.5, 192.168.0.6, 192.168.0.7.

This the setting in docker-compose file:

```
  redis-exporter:
    image: oliver006/redis_exporter:v1.12.0-alpine
    ports:
      - 9121:9121
    networks:
      - test_network
    command:
      - '--redis.addr=redis://192.168.0.5:6379'
      - '--redis.password=apasswd'
```

(I answered my own question;))

Answer (score 0):

Your answer helped a lot. Thanks.

In my case, I configured redis container, and redis-exporter container.
So, I set redis.addr as the name of container

```
redis-exporter:
image: oliver006/redis_exporter:v1.12.0-alpine
ports:
  - 9121:9121
networks:
  - test_network
command:
  - '--redis.addr=redis://<redis_container_name>:6379'
  - '--redis.password=apasswd'
```